# Julia Dataframes vs Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, julia

I am currently using python `pandas` and want to know if there is a way to output the data from pandas into julia `Dataframes` and vice versa. (I think you can call python from Julia with `Pycall` but I am not sure if it works with dataframes) Is there a way to call Julia from python and have it take in `panda`s dataframes? (without saving to another file format like csv)

When would it be advantageous to use Julia Dataframes than Pandas other than extremely large datasets and running things with many loops(like neural networks)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there is a library developed for this

`PyJulia` is a library used to interface with Julia using Python 2 and 3

https://github.com/JuliaLang/pyjulia

It is experimental but somewhat works

Secondly Julia also has a front end for `pandas` which is `pandas.jl`

https://github.com/malmaud/Pandas.jl

It looks to be just a wrapper for pandas but you might be able to execute multiple functions using julia's parallel features.

As for the which is better so far `pandas` has faster I/O according to this [reading csv in Julia is slow compared to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890893/reading-csv-in-julia-is-slow-compared-to-python)

Comment: Just to notice this is a 2014 answer, lots of things are changed in the Julia world in the meantime, e.g. CSV has become much faster

Answer (score 1):

I'm a novice at this sort of thing but have definitely been using both as of late. Truth be told, they seem very quite comparable but there is far more documentation, Stack Overflow questions, etc pertaining to Pandas so I would give it a slight edge. Do not let that fact discourage you however because Julia has some amazing functionality that I'm only beginning to understand. With large datasets, say over a couple gigs, both packages are pretty slow but again Pandas seems to have a slight edge (by no means would I consider my benchmarking to be definitive). Without a more nuanced understanding of what you are trying to achieve, it's difficult for me to envision a circumstance where you would even want to call a Pandas function while working with a Julia DataFrame or vice versa. Unless you are doing something pretty cerebral or working with really large datasets, I can't see going too wrong with either. When you say "output the data" what do you mean? Couldn't you write the Pandas data object to a file and then open/manipulate that file in a Julia DataFrame (as you mention)? Again, unless you have a really good machine reading gigs of data into either pandas or a Julia DataFrame is tedious and can be prohibitively slow.

Comment: the reason I am asking is the limiting factor for python in speed is the loops. Unless you are programming with `Cython`, custom functions requiring a for loop will slow your script down. Pandas only has a slight edge because Wes is terrific at coding to load CSV while julia just started on the Dataframes library.

Comment: When I say "output data" I mean if you call julia to perform a function you can get an answer back. Just like when you call matplotlib with Pycall you get something back in a format which julia understands. Basically I am looking for a library like `Pycall` but for Python similar to `Ironpython` which is used for C#, `Cython` for C, and `Jython` for Java

Comment: Again for some reason (probably my own obtuseness), I still can't parse what you are trying to do. You can call python from Julia, and, moreover, you can absolutely write code/functions in C and call it in Julia directly. It's fast and easy. I have only done this with something very very simple, although conceptually I'd imagine it would work the same way irrespective of the nature of the code.

Comment: I am trying to call Julia from python. So if I create a function in julia I can call it and hope that python accepts the output data type.

Comment: [PyPy](http://pypy.org) is a new implementation of Python which is much faster than normal Python, but I do not know whether pandas works with PyPy.