# Convert Julia Dataframe to Python Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, julia

I am trying to convert a PyCall.jlwrap ('Julia') object to a Pandas dataframe. I'm using PyJulia to run an optimization algorithm in Julia, which spits out a dataframe object as a result.  I would like to convert that object to a Pandas dataframe.

This is a similar question as posed 5 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322025/julia-dataframes-vs-python-pandas). However, there is not any code to suggest how to accomplish the transfer.

Any help would be useful!

Here is the code I currently have set-up. It's not that useful to know what is happening in the background of my 'optimization_program' but just to know that what is returned by the 'run_hybrid' and 'run_storage' commands returns a data frame:

```py
### load in necessary modules for pyjulia    
from julia import Main as jl 

##load my user defined module
jl.include("optimization_program_v3.jl")

##run function from module
results = jl.run_hybrid(generic_inputs)

##test type of item returned
jl.typeof(results)
returns: <PyCall.jlwrap DataFrame>

##try to convert to pandas
test = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

> Value Error  Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in ()
>
> ----> 1 test = pd.DataFrame(results)
>
> in **init**(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
>
> 420                 dtype=values.dtype, copy=False)
> 421             else:
> 422                 raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
>
> 423
>
> 424         NDFrame.**init**(self, mgr, fastpath=True)
>
> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: It would be useful to show what have you tried already.

Comment: can't you write it as `csv` and then read it in Python ?

Comment: Thanks @drec4s I have added some code.

Comment: @furas, I realize that is an option but I'd rather keep data management internal as I need to manipulate the final output using Python Pandas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get an error (reading a Julia DataFrame in Python), if I use the [DataFrames.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl) package. However, it seems to work nicely with the [Pandas.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Pandas.jl) package:

```
>>> from julia import Main as jl
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> jl.eval('using Pandas')
>>> res = jl.eval('DataFrame(Dict(:age=>[27, 29, 27], :name=>["James", "Jill", "Jake"]))')
>>> jl.typeof(res)
#<PyCall.jlwrap PyObject>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(res)
>>> df
    age   name
0   27  James
1   29   Jill
2   27   Jake
```

This was tested on Win10, with Python 3.8.2, and Julia 1.3.1

Comment: is there a way to do it the other way around, namely, to convert a pandas dataframe to a julia dataframe (e.g. when the work is mainly done in python and only the bottlenecks are to be performed in Julia)?

Comment: To be more precise: we can do `jl.dfj = df` but `jl.dfj` is a `PyObject` and not a dataframe (even when using the package `DataFrames`