# is python pandas, python Dask faster than julia CSV in the first time loading?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, julia

I have a CSV file which is 40.0kb. I tried both in pandas(python3.7) and CSV(julia1.4.2). I found python pandas is much faster than Julia CSV.  however, Julia is faster than python in every case. why reading CSV is slower in Julia? I am repeating this question because I found at the first time pandas is faster than Julia then I tried this again and again in Julia. then Julia is fast . but for the first time, Julia takes time.

```
#Julia
using CSV
 @time df=CSV.read("C:/Users/hafez/personal/r/tutorial forstudents/Book2.csv")
 **time  : 6.203511 seconds (8.55 M allocations: 409.590 MiB, 1.29% gc time)**
```

6.203511 seconds is the first time, I got, then I reload it then it shows time is 0.0034. I didn't understand why It showing different time.

```
#python 
import pandas as pd
import time
start=time.time()
df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/hafez/personal/r/tutorial for students/Book2.csv")
print(time.time()-start)
**time : 0.029919862747192383**



#python dask
import time
start=time.time()
df=dd.read_csv("C:/Users/hafez/personal/r/tutorial for students/Book2.csv")
print(time.time()-start)
**time: 0.0438847541809082**
```

I think python dask is so faster than Julia in case of reading a file.

Comment: @JohnZwinck , that post is 6 years old. I thought Julia improved.

Comment: @HafezAhmad: Well if you say it is this slow today, I guess it has not improved enough.

Comment: You are measuring here the compilation time of `CSV.jl` not the csv parsing time. You need to use `@btime` from BenchmarkTools or call `@time` twice and use the second measurement.

Comment: Here is an up-to-date benchmark https://towardsdatascience.com/the-great-csv-showdown-julia-vs-python-vs-r-aa77376fb96   I propose to reopen this question since the statements from 2016 are outdated indeed

Comment: I think it is better to keep the previous answer up-to-date as it is likely to be refrenced. I have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890893/reading-csv-in-julia-is-slow-compared-to-python/62619669#62619669 a quick benchmark there.

Comment: yeah, this is actually, not duplicated , I was just confused about what's wrong in my PC. I found a different time in Julia. at first, Julia took so much time than pandas. but python dask can handle so fast.